# User that seems to review all low quality posts as "Looks OK"

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a person that seems to press "Looks OK" on pretty much everything in the low quality review queue even when they are obviously not an answer. I've seen this at least ten times from  the same user and as I don't have 10k reputation to see deleted posts I thought I'd show an example of a recent one not yet deleted:

[image: Low quality posts review]

Everyone makes occasional mistakes and fortunately most do get deleted but they seem to either not pay attention or not know what should be deleted. Perhaps a moderator could check their review history and bring it to their attention? Because it only takes two "looks OK" to remove something from the low quality queue it can leave things like the following around when one other person makes a mistake, maybe by a simple wrong click:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/141596

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An everday problem ... :(

I check my raised flags if they are declined or disputed and often I've to raise a second mod flag to get non-answers deleted.

Don't understand that it seems to hard to read before clicking something. If I'm not sure, I better push *"Skip"*

@Reviewers **please** take some time.