# Moderators: Please take action against blatant bad reviewing

Tags: feature-request

There are an alarming number of complaints spanning several years about robo-reviewing on this site.

- [Reviewers: Please stop pressing "Looks OK" when it's not](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2688)
- [Report reviewers - temporary retract review permissions?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2575)
- [Quality of review process](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/500)
- [Valid Flag disputed](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2589)
- [User that seems to review all low quality posts as "Looks OK"](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2468)
- [Posts reviewing without observing](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2568)
- [why my flag is marked as disputed?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2491)

I have have had a recommended closure flag declined on a [blatantly off-topic question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/366016/what-is-the-recommended-npk-ratio-for-tomato-plants) called *'What is the recommended NPK ratio for tomato plants?'* because apparently the reviewers voted to leave it open from review. I don't know much about Magento but I know it has nothing to do with fertilizing tomato plants or whatever. I am not going to name specific users but I believe moderator intervention (warnings and/or review-only suspensions) should be taken to stop reviewers who [consistently](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2688/reviewers-please-stop-pressing-looks-ok-when-its-not#comment5720_2688) vote that blatant non-answers look OK or that blatantly off-topic questions should be left open. I am not sure if this site is eligible for [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/1377755) but I still believe blatantly and objectively bad reviewers should not just be left off the hook.

Comment: This is still happening... I'm still getting a couple of reviewers consistently reviewing incorrectly. Some review suspensions are in order.