# Would using 'very low quality' flags on questions be appropriate on this site?

Tags: discussion, flagging

In the past I noticed that there were [problems with robo-reviewing](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2691/112264). As such, recommended closure flags are broken, because they are going to be declined by reviewers leaving questions open, even if they are blatantly off-topic. Declined flags penalize flaggers.

However, a 'stronger' flag is the 'very low quality' flag. These can only be declined by moderators, and send the questions to a moderator queue in addition to the Low Quality Posts queue. Even if the reviewers there click Looks OK the flag will be disputed rather than declined.

As such, would it be appropriate to use 'very low quality' flags for questions that should be closed on this site?

Comment: In fairness, the new moderator seems to be pretty active (and accurate) in the Low-quality Answers queue. For the ones "disputed" before the new mod was elected, I have simply mod-flagged explaining what happened, and they have been deleted appropriately. For questions, this is probably better than sending it to Triage with VLQ.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Good for the new mod :) (Btw, there is no Triage on this site. Only on Stack Overflow and Physics.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. That's probably for the best. I gave up on that queue a long time ago.